# Add Entity to a specific solution - CRM 2016 SDK

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

Can I select solution in SDK while creating custom entity?
I have created a patch for solution and now I want to show new custom entities created through sdk only in that patch not any other solution. 
How can i do that.
**Thanks**

Comment: Have a look at: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Actually I want to add enitity through sdk i.e through C# Code, yes i know that all entites are there in the default solution but what i want is that if I clone new patch from a solution and if I ceate new field or entity it should appear in the newly created patch because that patch solution will have only those entities which are created in that specific solution, so here is the scenario. 1- I clone new patch from solution (I have its unique name) 2- I create new custom entity through code. 3- Is there any way we can specify while creating field that go in this specific solution?

Answer (score 1):

When you create an entity, it is created in the database and is available to be added to any unmanaged solution.  If you want the entity to appear in a specific solution, you have to add it to the solution after you create it.

There is no way to get an entity to appear only in your solution, it will always be visible in the default solution as well (all entities are always visible in the default solution with the exception of system entities, many of those are hidden).

Comment: Thanks.
Actually I want to add enitity through sdk i.e through C# Code, yes i know that all entites are there in the default solution but what i want is that if I clone new patch from a solution and if I ceate new field or entity it should appear in the newly created patch because that patch solution will have only those entities which are created in that specific solution, so here is the scenario. 
1- I clone new patch from solution (I have its unique name)
2- I create new custom entity through code.
3- Is there any way we can specify while creating field that go in this specific solution?

Comment: Not while creating it because any component you create will be added to the default solution.  But after you create it, try using use AddSolutionComponentRequest to add it to your patch.